# MySQL) How CONCAT() function works inside of REPEAT LOOP?

Tags: mysql, function, loops, repeat, concatenation

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE RepeatDemo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'test string';

    REPEAT
        SET result = CONCAT(result, counter, ',');
        SET counter = counter + 1;
    UNTIL counter >= 10
    END REPEAT;

    -- display result
    SELECT result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
CALL RepeatDemo(); // = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
```

I'm learning basic loop using `REPEAT` keyword from [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-repeat-loop/) website. By passing `REPEAT` keyword, the variable `result` shows every single numbers 1 to 9 through `CONCAT()` function.

What I don’t understand is how, and why the variable `result` refers to every each numbers in the code.

The tutorial says use the `CONCAT()` function to add the `counter` value to the `result` variable (sounds like overwriting):

> append `counter` value to the `result` variable using the CONCAT() function . . .

I googled about [CONCAT() w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php), but couldn’t find about overwriting.

How this code works?

Comment: Tip: First stop should be the [official documentation for `CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) not some third-rate "w3" type site.

Comment: The way concat works is pretty straight-forward, and it doesn't behave differently in a loop. Imagine if you didn't have a loop and instead you did `CONCAT(result, 1, ',')` and then `CONCAT(result, 2, ',')` and so on.

Comment: @tadman So what I understand is the value `count` is going to actually stock into the `result` variable in every loops like this: `Loop 1st: (empty string)` / `Loop 2nd: 1,` / `Loop 3rd: 1,2,` / `Loop 4th: 1,2,3,` / `Loop 5th: 1,2,3,4` . . .  `Final Loop: 1 to 9` is my observation correct?

Comment: Yes, but there's always a comma on the end because one is always added last, but otherwise that's the idea.

Comment: @tadman Got it. Thank you for giving me tip.